# Multiprocessing and a list as output returns error: local variable '' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7, list, multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing for a project of mine. I have a code that already works fine an i want to adapt it. I realised that when there is a list in the workers method  i get the following error; local variable 'RouteInfo' referenced before assignment. Any suggestions?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  time_start = time.clock()      
  AREA_ID, PARENT_ID, routes_data, routingPlanID, StationName = getRouteDetails(StationName, PARENT_ID, AREA_ID)
  copyDailyABPDetail(PARENT_ID, AREA_ID)
  AREA_ID=AREA_ID.decode('utf-8')    
  StationsList = [unicode(item[0]) for item in routes_data]

  func = partial(testMethod, AREA_ID, PARENT_ID, routingPlanID, StationNameDic)

  # declare number of cores to use
  cpuNum = multiprocessing.cpu_count() 

  # Create the pool object  
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpuNum) 

  # Fire off list to worker function.  
  results=pool.map(func,StationsList)

  pool.close()  
  pool.join()  
  print results

  time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)

 def testMethod(AREA_ID, PARENT_ID, routingPlanID, StationNameDic, StationName):
   try:
      print "Processing: ",StationName
      RouteInfo = ["ALL", "ALL", "PRESERVE_BOTH", ["OnewaySelective","Footway","Steps","Path","Tolls"], "OR", "Α,Β,Γ", "NGIS", "RA"]
      print RouteInfo

    except Exception as e:
        # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
        import traceback, sys
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        print "An error occured on line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
        print str(e)
    return StationName, RouteInfo
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: Also, a tip for pasting code into questions/answers: after pasting, immediately select what you pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. Then you won't risk adding indentation errors by trying to fix the formatting manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved there was an error in my code (variable StatioName had an utf-8 issue), so the variable RouteInfo was never been assigned.